# Hive/ Impala query group by query for total success and failed record

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, impala, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to add the group by clause on the impala/Hive table but its not working.

I am having the jobs details table which having job name and status column.

```
Table jobs_details :
---------------------
Job name       status
---------------------
A              failed
B              Failed
A              success
A              failed
----------------------------------
I want the below type output :
----------------------------------
Job name           failed_count success_count
 A                      2               1
 B                      1               0
```

I tried to use the group by clause on job name but it's showing me total count ( failed + success )

Answer (score 0):

Below query might help you in getting the desired result.

```
SELECT job,
Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'Success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Success, 
Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed
FROM   temp
GROUP  BY job
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I tried your query but failed/success count is zero also not showing all jobs. I used the count instead of SUM but looks like the same issue.

Comment: Use lowercase and try - `SELECT job,
Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Success, 
Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed
FROM   temp
GROUP  BY job`

Comment: I just tried the same by logging to the 
hue website. Got the result over then and then shared the query... https://demo.gethue.com/hue/accounts/login?next=/